# What is the right way (resp. folder) to save files under Android 11 (API30)?

Tags: java, android, permissions, filesystems, scoped-storage

My Android-APP creates text files that have to be read by other apps.

I originally chose the following directory, which no longer works:
*Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory((Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS))*

Right now I'm trying the directory:
*getFilesDir()*

The problem here is that no other app can access this folder.

I'm puzzled as I simply don't know which directory I can use for an exchange between apps.

Comment: Use `ACTION_CREATE_DOCUMENT` / `ActivityResultContracts.CreateDocument` and let the user decide where on the user's device (or the user's cloud storage providers) the user wants you to put the user's text content. Any location that the user chooses will be available to other apps that use `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT`.

Comment: You can write all your files to that Documents directory. Other apps let the user choose that directory with ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE. Upon which that app has access to all files in it.

Comment: @blackapps
Yes, but after every reinstall the ownership of the created files are gone: listFiles() returns null

Comment: No not null but an empty list. Indeed. Wel then also use ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT_TREE.